# Detecting FPU presence on Android

Tags: android, optimization, mobile, fpu

I want to get the most performance of my mobile application on Android. I would like to know if someone is aware of a trick to check if the phone possesses an FPU.

After some research it seems that using `FloatMath` class is slower on a unit that possesses an FPU, so I would like to have best of both worlds.

Most newer phones have an FPU, but I would like to get the most performance the device can offer.

Comment: Has anybody made a processor without a FPU in the last 15 years?

Comment: Some android phone don't have one, thats the point. HTC Hero for instance

Comment: @gimpycpu I'm calling shenanigans. I can't understand a CPU not having an FPU

Comment: Well if no one know I will just stick with FloatMath class unless I notice bad performance on more mainstream type of phones.

Comment: For those calling shenanigans, please know that at least one popular early android phone (the G1) did not have an FPU. The fact is referenced in Google's floating point advice: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#avoidfloat

Comment: @gimpycpu Didn't you mean "After some research it seems that using FloatMath class is slower on a unit that DOES NOT possess an FPU" instead?

Comment: @Tiago Hey Tiago, that question is quite old now and not very applicable anymore.

According to google nowaway Floatmath is faster because most(all) devices have FPU and it get optimized correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a Linux kernel underneath, and at least the default Android configuration will mount `procfs`. That means you can look into `/proc/cpuinfo`, which on an ARM system looks something like:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 249.96
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x1
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 3
[ ... ]
```

If the "`Features`" line lists at least `vfp`, then the ARM SoC has an FPU.

You should be able to read `/proc/cpuinfo` via Dalvik/Java interfaces, just like a normal file, no privileged access or anything required. I'm not a Java programmer, so leaving that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a very old thread, for anyone like me landed here by google may find this useful. Here I am showing how we can do it using NDK (C++) as the Java-way is already given.

Using NDK, by including [cpu-features.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.h), we can utilize a number of API and predefined macros to detect the availability of FPU.

For **32 bit** processor, you should check one of `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFPv3`, `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFPv2`, `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFP_D32`, `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFP_FP16` or `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFP_FMA` on the return value of `android_getCpuFeatures()` which will ensure that your processor is armed with an FPU.

For **64 bit**, please check `ANDROID_CPU_ARM64_FEATURE_FP` flag.

Additionally, call `android_getCpuFamily()` to get CPU family/architecture (ARM/MIPS, 32/64 bit etc).

The [cpufeatures library manual](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features.html#functions) has everything to include and use it in your project.