# Android floating point math performance

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an [Android application](https://github.com/dbyrne/Fractoid) which uses the NDK to execute a large amount of floating point math.

I just acquired a new Galaxy Nexus.  To my surprise, my app runs MUCH slower than it should.  I suspect this is because most devices are using hardware acceleration and the Galaxy Nexus is not.  If I perform an operation which does not require floating point math, the Galaxy Nexus performs how I would expect.

Here are the CPU/GPU specs and sample timings for several devices.  I've normalized the stats to take into account display resolution:

```
Droid
CPU: TI OMAP 3430 (ARM Cortex-A8 600 MHz underclocked to 550 MHz)
GPU: PowerVR SGX530
Instruction Set: ARMv7
Test Run: 1,980 pixels per second

Galaxy Nexus
CPU: TI OMAP 4460 (ARM Cortex-A9 dual-core 1.2 GHz)
GPU: PowerVR SGX540
Instruction Set: ARMv7
Test Run: 2,253 pixels per second

Droid Incredible
CPU: QSD8650 (Qualcomm Snapdragon 1 GHz)
GPU: Adreno 200
Instruction Set: ARMv7
Test Run: 4,571 pixels per second
```

I have this configuration in my `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

I have not re-compiled my code with NDK-r7, but I don't understand why this would make such a dramatic difference.  Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: could you quantify `MUCH slower`?

Comment: @WarrenFaith I've updated the question with actual numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use
`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a`
to force use of the v7a instructions only.
I could imagine that the new CPU is not detected as supporting v7a instructions and that thus the no-FPU code is used at runtime as a fallback.

Comment: This worked.  However, this is pretty depressing, because now I have no way of putting one app on the market which all phones support.  I'd hate to post two different applications just because of this.

Comment: Personally I've been looking into renderscript direction for compatibility. And not only for supporting different kinds of CPUs but also for easy to implement multiprocessor support and possible GPU utilization.

Comment: You can include different versions of a native library within the same app; remember that the libs are loaded _at runtime_ through your Java code. Maybe its possible to do the FPU detection inside your app, e.g. like [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161184/detecting-fpu-presence-on-android), and then load the corresponding native lib.

Answer (score 7):

This StackOverflow question may be the cause of the poor performance on your Galaxy Nexus: [Galaxy Nexus - wrong CPU ABI being selected during install time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714671/galaxy-nexus-wrong-cpu-abi-being-selected-during-install-time).

That seems to be a bug. I've tested it also by creating a small project using native code and indeed Galaxy Nexus chooses the wrong library (armeabi instead of armeabi-v7a).

I've reported this bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25321 , with the sample project attached on the bug. Please star it to bring attention to Android engineers.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem.  Starred.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there are 2 cores in the processor. Thus, you have 600 Mhz for one core. So if your math method uses only one thread this can be an answer. Although, I do not understand why it is 2 times slower (comparable time can be explained).

Comment: I have seen a phone marketed as "2 GHz" when in fact it was a dual-core 1 GHz phone, but I assure you the Galaxy Nexus has two 1.2 GHz processors.

Comment: You bring up a good point that I should multithread my calculation code.  Especially since it would be trivial to parallelize it.