# Extremely slow OGG decodeing on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, soundpool

I have encountered a really weird issue on my Galaxy Nexus. What I'm trying to do is load 48 OGG samples into SoundPool at the start of my service (music related application). Files are 11-15K each. Loading code is simple:

```
for (String note : sm) { // 48 iterations
    int soundId = soundPool.load(getResources().getAssets().openFd(note), 1);
    loadedSoundsMap.put(note, soundId);
}
```

I have measured that on my Nexus One 2.3.6 I loads in 1-2 seconds. But on a brand new Galaxy Nexus 4.0.2 it loads in 9 seconds!

I really doubt it's a file IO taking so much time to read 1mb total, so I think something is screwed up in decompressor implementation.

Can anyone suggest what could cause such slow work?

P. S. Mp3 gives about the same picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the `SoundPool` implementation. Audio hardware works in front of uncompressed data - PCM, so as `SoundPool` keeps all sounds loaded, it decompresses OGG or MP3 files to WAV. In order to improve UX, you can run a thread which decodes from OGG to WAV files on application start. When running a player if sound is converted - use WAV file, OGG otherwise. Here's a link to nice OGG decoder: [libvorbis-libogg-android](https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android). Keep in mind that OGG decoder decodes to raw PCM, so you have to add WAV header.

On Android L there's also an issue with AwesomePlayer, when loading any file to SoundPool takes very long time. Switching to NuPlayer in Developer options helps, but it should be fixed by Android team somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be related to this: [Galaxy Nexus - wrong CPU ABI being selected during install time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714671/galaxy-nexus-wrong-cpu-abi-being-selected-during-install-time)

and this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25321

Comment: on the other hand AFAIK each phone has native libs compiled specifically for its processor, because, obviously, you know which device they will run unlike APK.