# Encog runs too slow on Android, what to do?

Tags: android, performance, neural-network, encog

I've developed an application using Encog 3.1.0 for desktop, but my intent was always to port it to Android platform. Well, in desktop platform it runs nicely, very quick, it takes seconds to finish the job. On the other hand, when I run the same code on Android it becomes very slow.

My question is: Is there any difference on how to program Engog NN for desktop or Android? What should I do in order to run my app on Android in an acceptable time?

PS: my device is a Samsung Galaxy tab 2

Thanks all,
B.Ramon

Comment: Please, if you got the solution, share with us, I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Do you mean training or querying a network on Android? In general I'd recommend to pre-train your networks on a PC. Querying should not be too slow if your smartphone has a hardware FPU unless you have a really huge network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What hardware platform are you using? I am planning on providing more "official" support for Android soon with Encog.  I plan to look into some optimizations.

Basically, the problem seems to be the speed of the Java math libraries on the Android platform.  Other packages have similar issues.  You can see more here.  [Android floating point math performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617789/android-floating-point-math-performance)

I believe the means to make Encog faster on the Android is to make use of the Android NDK or possibly make use of some of the routines from BLAS.

Comment: The hardware is a [Samsung Galaxy Tab 2](http://www.samsung.com/br/consumer/cellular-phone/cellular-phone-tablets/tablet/GT-P5100TSMZTO), i'm going to try using the Android NDK, I made some tests and I noticed there were some problems on training step, after  some changes on code, it is running faster a little bit. Thanks for response